# Woocommerce product gallery images not showing in RTL

Tags: html, css, woocommerce, product, gallery

I am working on woocommerce website, that the single page has a problem.
The problem is, the product gallery images are not showing in RTL mode.
The link for my website is: https://iraqs.net/anwar-saida/shop/fauteuil-de-jardin-sur-pied

When I open the console and write some css codes, it works. But when I try to copy the same codes and put in the css stylesheet file. Does not work.

`.single-product .product-single-main .product-wrapper { direction: rtl; }`

`.single-product .product-single-main .product-wrapper .woocommerce-product-gallery { direction: rtl; }`

I have tried these all, but not working for me.